# how to add onclick event to a programmatically created link button in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic-programming, asplinkbutton

I want to display the products which i get them from my DB using dataset in a table dynamically because of the number of products in each store is vary , and when the user click on a product from the table i will display the clicked product details on the screen .

the problem is that i have added a link button programmatically in each cell of the table but the click event handler not working .

Please how can i add a link button , and click event handler dynamically? and how can i get the id of the clicked button inside the event handler method(ShowProductDetails)?

this is my code

**products.aspx**

```
 </asp:Content>
   <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <table  style=" width: 700px;" align="center">
<tr style="width:100%;">

<td align="center" width="50%" >Stores </td>
<td align="right" width="50%" >
<asp:DropDownList ID="StoresDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="120px">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td >
<asp:table id="ProductsTBL" runat ="server" style="width: 700px;" 
        align="center" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="3px">
</asp:table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<asp:Panel  runat ="server" id="ProductDetails_Panel" visible ="false">

<asp:Label ID="selectedProduct" runat ="server" Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
</td>



</tr>
    </table>


   </asp:Content>
```

**Products.aspx.vb**

```
 Imports System.Data



Partial Class Admin_ViewProducts
     Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Dim con As New Conection
Dim ds_Products As New DataSet 
Dim dr_Products As DataRow
Dim ds_Stores As New DataSet
Dim dr_Stores As DataRow


Dim sB As New LinkButton()


Protected Sub StoresDDL__Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StoresDDL.Init

    StoresDDL.Items.Clear()
    StoresDDL.Items.Add("Select a store")
    StoresDDL.DataValueField = 0

    Try

            ds_Stores = con.get_data("select storeid , storeName from Store ")

        End If

        Dim x As Integer = 1
        For Each Me.dr_stores In ds_stores.Tables(0).Rows
            If (dr_stores.IsNull(0) = False) Then
                StoresDDL.Items.Add(dr_stores.Item(1))

                StoresDDL.Items(x).Value = dr_stores.Item(0)

                x = x + 1
            End If

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub StoresDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StoresDDL.SelectedIndexChanged


    ds_products = con.get_data("select productid ,productName from Product where storeid=" & StoresDDL.SelectedValue ")
    Dim y As Integer = 1

    Dim NOClmns As Integer = 3
    Dim NOCells As Integer = ds_products.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    Dim NORows As Integer = Math.Round(NOCells / 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)


    ' Current row count
    Dim rowCtr As Integer
    ' Current cell counter.
    Dim cellCnt As Integer

    Dim productCount As Integer = 0
    While productCount <> ds_products.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        For rowCtr = 1 To NORows
            Dim tRow As New TableRow()
            For cellCount = 1 To 4 'For NOCells = 1 To cellCnt

                Dim tCell As New TableCell()
                'Dim s As New HyperLink()
                sB = New LinkButton()
                sB.ID = ds_products.Tables(0).Rows(productCount).Item("productName").ToString
                sB.Text = ds_products.Tables(0).Rows(productCount).Item("productName").ToString

                AddHandler sB.Click, AddressOf Me.ShowProductDetails

                tCell.Controls.Add(sB)
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell)
                productCount += 1
            Next cellCount   'NOCells
            ' Add new row to table.
            ProductsTBL.Rows.Add(tRow)

        Next rowCtr

    End While
End Sub

Protected Sub ShowProductDetails(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)



    ProductDetails_Panel.Visible = True
    selectedProduct.Visible = True
    selectedProduct.Text = "test"


     End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: "this is my code but it didn't work" - What didn't work? Do have a read of [ask].

Comment: @Enigmativity , I was talking about the ShowProductDetails method its not called when i click the link button

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work, you will want to use the Command Event for the link button and pass a CommandArgument, the product ID.

So:

```
sb.CommandArgument = ds_products.Tables(0).Rows(productCount).Item("productID")
sb.CommandName = "clicked"
sb.OnCommand="LinkButton_Command"
```

Then, add an event to the code behind:

```
   Sub LinkButton_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs) 
      If e.CommandName = "clicked" Then
           Process Request
      End IF
   End Sub
```

But, if it were me, I would bind to a DataGrid or Repeater, rather than create my own table...